# Main PHP way to verify(or sesame) $_POST submit

Tags: php, forms

I would like to add sesame and verify it when user come to action page example:

```
if(isset($_POST["contact-us"])) {
//some code
}elseif(isset($_POST["site-feedback"])) {
//some code
}else{get_error('form');}
```

my current thought is to add `$_SESSION["SESAMEOPEN"]["contact-us"]='uniquesalt'` for say, contact-us.php then the form send to the action page to verify.

The problem I faced is : for instance the user open another page while visiting contact-us.php, the user can still reach action page by manipulate a `input type="submit" name="contact-us"`. While method of checking redirect page seems to be able to be spoofed too.

Whats the main-stream way of verifying the action page? What I want is the user can only reach the action.php from the specific form.php .

Comment: Have you tried salt-hash tokens? They're time sensitive.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: The CSRF cheat sheet seems to be quite useful, I'll take some time research on its working mechanism

Comment: I think you should manage a token list with time in $_SESSION Variable. If user open a contact page a new token should be added to that list. On submit a contact form match the received token with time ( lets say 10 min). If match contact form will be accepted otherwise deny and display contact form again with new token (added to session). You can also remove token from token list which have expired (say 10 min).